# "SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session" when running Selenium Test Java with Chrome Driver on Mac

Tags: java, google-chrome, security, selenium-webdriver, junit

I get in console :

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

When I run a Selenium Junit Test with Chrome Driver on macbook. I checked this is the right driver I'm using with my chrome browser version. I get a security warning from the OS saying that the editor of `chromedriver.exe` is unknown. I gave access to it in settings but didn't change anything.

I tried all methods possible to import the chrome driver, on local machine with absolute path, with `WebDriverManager` etc.
It's not a version problem, I'm using `Chrome v110`.
Nothing works, I changed security MacBook's settings to enable driver working but didn't change anything each time I launch the JUnit test.